# Tuple argument type inference in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is it possible to achieve the following in Typescript:

I want the type of `state.initial` to be deduced as a tuple based on the input to `takeConfig`. It would also be nice to deduce the return type of `initialState` based on the type of the `state` property of the component function's `props` argument (Although the latter, I believe, is not possible without changing this API).

```js
type State1 = { a: string };
type State2 = { b: string };

function Component1(props: { state: State1 }) {}
function Component2(props: { state: State2 }) {}

const state = takeConfig([
    {
        component: Component1,
        initialState: () => ({
            a: "a"
        }) // return type here is deduced to be State1
    },
    {
        component: Component2,
        initialState: () => ({
            b: "b"
        }) // return type here is deduced to be State2
    },
]);


// type here is deduced to be [State1, State2]
state.initial
```

Thanks!

Comment: If your question is "is it possible" and not "how to do it" then the answer is **yes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If your question is "is it possible" and not "how to do it" then the answer is **yes**.

Let's first define the type of an object that your `takeConfig` function would take:

```
type Conf<C extends (...args: any[]) => any> = {
    component: C;
    initialState: () => Parameters<C>[0]["state"];
};
```

Then we'll make a type to infer all the component function types in the tuple:

```
type InferConfs<C extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = {
    [K in keyof C]: C[K] extends Conf<infer Comp> ? Conf<Comp> : C[K];
};
```

Next we'll need a type to give us `state.initial` in a similar manner to `InferConfs`:

```
type JustStates<C extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = {
    [K in keyof C]: C[K] extends Conf<infer _> ? ReturnType<C[K]["initialState"]> : C[K];
};
```

Finally let's create a type to hold `JustStates`:

```
type ReturnedState<Confs extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = {
    initial: JustStates<Confs>;
};
```

And also a type to remove the `readonly` that `as const` will give:

```
type MakeNotReadonly<T> = {
    -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K];
};
```

Now we put all of these together to define our `takeConfig` function:

```
function takeConfig<C extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>>(conf: InferConfs<C>): ReturnedState<MakeNotReadonly<InferConfs<C>>> { ... }
```

You must implement the function yourself, however. I am just helping with the types.

The basic principle is that TypeScript can infer the general type that we pass to `takeConfig`, and we use `InferConfs` to further narrow the types of the configs. Then in the return type we infer the configs yet again, then do some type transformations (`JustState`) on it and return it.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIEYoF4oG8rwFxQGdgAnASwDsBzKAXwG4BYAKFElgSQCZ0soAjfETJVajJswBmAV3IBjYKQD25KAGFFAWzDKI5YMgAUYYorAF82Iogj4411DQCUWGpJnylK9Vp17ORkzMLQg4bdmtuJxdmZlZodXIJAB5VKAgADyRyABMCKAMAOiL4YkpzHHIQAG0AXWc0AD4KkCaMTGYoTqhZTW1yXWB8VTEuqApSBXgAGzskfAN6poAFEvgNCCRiAhSGqoAGGqqAIiskI5qxehiWcGgASUSIYgSJbdSMrNyoACUIeGzlFMQABBYjEeAgJIyADW5EUAHdyA1WlgOl0qgBpMYqaEQECKCRqGpDTE1NKZXRfF5JCgSJ5qXpNAD8DMSKUZUBJGIuzCu4hubAAUlIiLMIG9yZ88r9-oCQWCIVDyLCEUiUe0mKNMdioLj8YTVMS1KTJZS8tTafSAPrMn4bKTEcgAFVuKVJx3GkxmoXOTS5PKYfNitztwAd-WyYvZiTyHzNdtl5CBoPBkJhcMRyJ4GtGntI03wwtFoTeyleDUuYmDbAAsvBcQA5RTAGUApOQp3qtGdAC0xD+baBUG1FF1eIJUCdRqdpMr12yEFkUxK0GkcgUyigCFxL1IlBSppy0oHcpTivTquRBh6iXwDzpzzLbwajnwvzDjogkdCSTrjebrZykk95PC8z7IlWTA3kQITWDw24QLulAGFU3aopqoxdD0Pj9HoQy9L4+gADRobm5ATPm3rWPMiz5DmmEMXgUBHPARykV0UQAPScVA-YfiocRQAAFk80CkHkC7ZFIshfluij8NAYrIGhNAkRhnT0Qx2F9AM+E4QMnBqQxnR5tMYo0egTQGJpxmdAIzF8Gx6mYVxPF8eGW4hiJ-ZjBJX7SbJwDyXwimhJwKlqWS8B5NBwCOJB3GeWw3liX5UkydkckKcOSlEeEXA1MwpwQAUplTMwiVdAAekyQA)