# Object with one key's value dependent on another key's value

Tags: typescript

What would be the best way of achieving this effect (note: this is not valid syntax - consider it a pseudocode):

```js
type Config = {
  [key: string]: <T> {
    params: T,
    doSth: (params: T) => void,
  },
}
```

I.e. the generic `T` type is different for every key's value (which is an object itself), but at the same time it's being reused within that value (object) under different fields. Also, `T` is derived from the `params` field. With that I could do:

```js
const config: Config = {
  a: {
    params: { x: 123 },
    doSth: params => {}, // Type of "params" is "{ x: 123 }"
  },
  b: {
    params: { y: 'asd' },
    doSth: params => {}, // Type of "params" is "{ y: 'asd' }"
  },
}
```

To my surprise, googling this doesn't yield matching results, even though it seems relatively useful *pattern* - there's a lot of similar problems but not really the same. Some solutions to those, that I tried to apply - all failed.

Comment: You're looking for [*existentially qualified generics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), also called "existential types", but TypeScript has no direct support for them (and neither do most languages with generics).  There are ways to emulate them (like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYkj2N)) or work around them (like @TJCrowder's answer).  See the answers to the linked questions for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you can't do in TypeScript with types alone, sometimes you need a function to help even if the function doesn't actually do anything at runtime. I *think* this is one of those times. Here's an example of a function that gets close to what you're describing:

```typescript
type ConfigEntry<T extends object> = {
    params: T;
    doSth: (params: T) => void;
};

function makeConfigEntry<T extends object>(obj: ConfigEntry<T>): ConfigEntry<T> {
    return obj;
}
```

Notice how `ConfigEntry` lets us relate the two places we'll be using that type. You'd use that function when defining the values of the properties:

```typescript
const config = {
    a: makeConfigEntry({
        params: { x: 123 },
        doSth: params => {}, // Type of `params` is `{ x: number; }`
        //     ^?
    }),
    b: makeConfigEntry({
        params: { y: "asd" },
        doSth: params => {}, // Type of `params` is `{ y: string; }`
        //     ^?
    }),
};
```

Note there's no `Config` type annotation on that. TypeScript will infer it from the object initializer.

But notice the types on `params` aren't quite what you wanted. TypeScript won't infer the types `{ x: 123; }` and `{ y: "asd"; }` from your objects. It will either infer `{ x: number; }` and `{ y: string; }`, or if you define the objects `as const`, it'll infer `{ readonly x: 123; }` and `{ readonly y: "asd"; }`:

```typescript
const config = {
    a: makeConfigEntry({
        params: { x: 123 } as const,
        doSth: params => {}, // Type of `params` is `{ readonly x: 123; }`
        //     ^?
    }),
    b: makeConfigEntry({
        params: { y: "asd" } as const,
        doSth: params => {}, // Type of `params` is `{ readonly y: "asd"; }`
        //     ^?
    }),
};
```

This is likely not quite what you wanted, but I think it's close, probably one of several approaches that are as close to what you want as you can get with today's TypeScript.

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmBRBwBOIA8AKlBAB7AQIAmAzlHAEYBWEAxsAHxQC8UA3gCgowqGACGOMQFsaALiiEA3EJFU4AZWAALeQApxkmfMIBKHlwBucFFWUBfZQKQBXBOxSIoUsQGsI8ZHQsXAJiMgpqOkYWdg5daPkA1ExsPCIOE0TEZOC0wi5BESgcCGBnHAR6ZnsBAVZEGmAoesC0Hn4VYTF5bz8koNSQXUKikQNpOX4oUnkARgAmAGYoOwAaTtG1TR0ofQkJs24CtagAelOFcGg4JCgAA3GZO6gUOju+afkEZykGCBxFCs7hsiudRiIAHoAfg2dhM6yKDB6vn82QGIWGILG+yMUxA8gARGIaFQCSsEeCoFttHpHjRDsdVmcLoQrvRbg8cTRnq97h98VBGjgUAg0IC7MDKcypdDYfCBA4gA) of the above

Comment: That works - thanks. It was also one of the solutions I tried before, but frankly, as you also pointed - feels very much like a hack. Any reason this cannot be done in TS without that bogus function?

Comment: @jaloc Without the function TypeScript has no incentive to attempt to infer the types. It's kind of like petals on a flower attracting pollinators. So if we only had that Config type, TypeScript wouldn't try to infer T.

Comment: This can actually be done with one function and one call to that function. You might get some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72143555/18244921). Good luck!

Comment: @jalooc - As catgirlkelly said, apparently we need it to pass the generic through. I asked one of those really knowledgeable TypeScript people (I think it was Titian Cernicova Dragomir) if he knew if there were plans for some kind of types-only thing for the situations where we need these do-nothing functions, and he said he didn't know of any -- probably because functions work, even if they feel hacky. :-) (To be clear: he isn't on the TypeScript project team, he just knows it backward and forward and is well-informed.)

Comment: How would you type the `config` variable in this case? It'd be like `{ [x: string]: ConfigEntry }` but you're missing a generic on ConfigEntry? How do you solve this?

Comment: @KasparPoland - There's no need to put a type on the `config` variable, TypeScript will infer it from the object literal. (You can see that in the playground link above. [I just added that link, it's odd I left it out originally.] Hover your mouse over `config` to see the type TypeScript infers.) But if you wanted to give it a type explicitly, it would be `{ a: ConfigEntry<{ x: number; }>; b: ConfigEntry<{ y: string; }>; }` (the type TypeScript infers).

Comment: @KasparPoland - I don't think it's what you meant, but **if** you wanted an index signature like the one you showed, you'd have to provide the type parameter to `makeConfigEntry` explicitly in order to make the type of `x`/`y` `number|string`: https://tsplay.dev/wOxGRN But I don't think that's what you meant.