# Get type of a function return using generic types

Tags: typescript

Originally I was trying to an get property in an object to only accept values from the keys of a data obj which I managed following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72329826/get-the-type-of-an-item-in-keyof-using-a-property-and-generic-types) very detailed response.

My types look like this:

```
type ExtendData = unknown | object | any[];

    interface Submodule<TData extends ExtendData, K extends keyof TData> {
        accessor: K;
        title?: string;
        element?: ({ submodule, issue, value }: { submodule: SomeKeyValueFunc<TData>, issue: number, value: TData[K] }) => void
        scroll?: boolean;
    }

    type SomeKeyValueFunc<TData> = { [K in keyof TData]-?: Submodule<TData, K> }[keyof TData];

    type SubModuleArrayArray<TData> = SomeKeyValueFunc<TData>[];

    interface Module<TData extends ExtendData> {
       title?: string;
       subModules: SubModuleArrayArray<TData>;
    }

const test: Module<{ a: string; b: number; c: { deepA: string; deepB: boolean } }>[] = [
  {
    title: 'Something',
    subModules: [
      {
        title: '',
        accessor: 'a',
        element: (props) => props.value // this is of type string.
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

`accessor` should only accept values that are keys of `TData`. Then `element` receives as a prop the whole `submodule` + a `value` which is the type of the `accessor` key

Thanks to the response and this: `element?: ElementType<SomeKeyValueFunc<TData> & { issue: number, value: TData[K] }>; //ElementType from React`. I was able to make it work and have the `value` returned in the `element` be of the type of the `accessor`

You can try the solution here in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBlA9gGwK4BcCWawSA3gLABQFS1SOAnjMgKIAeOEwAJgCIg4hIAvEizAA1sDQB3IgB8kaAEYArCPBxJ5IYHQDaAXQDcFE+Rq0GyAILxEUNACcAYsAA8AFV78kENh05QSKzsXF4gADRIANI+flyBYhB0aABmSJ58IAB8QkgAFJyZAFzpYQCUQjkZ-LpRRqZUNHjA7A4pCMgoWIpgaJxYGBAeYbEhAUFxPJmRMb5jCUmppZk5ZGbmNAh29g4lUcbrG7R4OIMA-CVQOA7NAOYHR9QQg5AtF-nESFDdvf2DkXgoN8IJEAG4gbDIAC+JU+3x6fQGEBK6EgUSSADUIVgIE5RPBhisAUCcSVgFgwIoIA4wdjkcsanUkFCKoIcqC0HhOI0jlB4A5MBh3oo0JgINoHjQoaZzPRGKg0GjMXS8cACdVsrlPrUkM0kIlkmkNfoALTvLoIv5DDUzHJQ3QGpbGg48izyi0AWURgysDgcIDovv9dEJ-BywlREHRdCxkNV6rCWQMLsOupa1PaiCQXqtoYEc38gWC-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) as well as some explanation to the problem

What I'm trying to extend now is having the `accessor` also accept a function which receives the data. That I managed with:

```
type AccesorFn<TData extends ExtendData, K extends keyof TData> = (data: TData) => TData[K];

interface Submodule<...> {
   accessor: AccesorFn<TData, K> | K
   ...
}

const test: Module<{ a: string; b: number; c: { deepA: string; deepB: boolean } }>[] = [
  {
    title: 'Something',
    subModules: [
      {
        title: '',
        accessor: (data) => data.a, // This works perfect, I get auto completion from data
        element: (props) => props.value // this should still be of type string but its any
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

which works very nice, the `accessor` now accepts a function that has as argument the original data.

The problem is that the value in the `element` now looses the type and I get this: `Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.` , and I'm not very sure how to get the value to infer the return type of the function **and** also from the single `key` if its **not** a function.

Comment: I get an error in the example that is supposed to "work": https://tsplay.dev/wXqx9N

Comment: @caTS Yep you are right, I edited the link to fix the error, it was because of the React stuff so I just removed all of it for this example